# Select option from Run Application Dialog

Tags: shortcut-keys

Is there a quick way (a keyboard shortcut) to select one of the options from the `Run Application` dialog cause right now I have to use the mouse to select the one I want.

For example when I type `code` I'd like to be able to move with the arrow key and then click enter to select the option I want. I tried with `Tab` and other keys but none worked.

[image]

Comment: I would assume you need to hit the "tab" key to get over the buttons and get to "run". Or "shift" "tab"; that might go 1 back and end up at "run".run

Comment: What are your desktop environment and Ubuntu version?